# install the Appstats middleware in a Flask Application

Tags: google-app-engine

So I am building an application using the Flask on Google's App Engine. The skelton code i am using can be found at.  https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-python-flask-skeleton.

I am trying to install Appstats middleware so I can track resource consumption on my webapp. The following link https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/appstats recommends using the following function to enable appstats on WSGI request handlers.

I can't find the module they are importing

```
from google.appengine.ext.appstats import recording
```

Where do I get this ? Its not in the skelton code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you read the rest of the document?  Specifically the setup section - https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/appstats#Python_Set_the_console_path
You need to enable appstats library as a builtin.

Have you done this ?

Comment: Yes I have added the builtins into app.yaml. However in the  appengine_config.py, when I add the following code def webapp_add_wsgi_middleware(app):
  from google.appengine.ext.appstats import recording
  app = recording.appstats_wsgi_middleware(app)
  return app , python can't resolve recording

Comment: appstats has been part of the SDK for ages, so you should be able to import it, you are are using running the dev_appserver etc.. - I know obvious question but just checking, others have tried to run main.py directly - things like that.